# error logs: client denied by server configuration

Tags: wordpress, apache, client, http-status-code-403

this is my error logs!! pls help me.. googlerbot can't crawl my website too. i'm using shared hosting.

> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:34 2014] [error] [client 198.143.34.33] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/markgiver/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:34 2014] [error] [client 198.143.34.33] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/markgiver/2014
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:30 2014] [error] [client 199.30.20.15] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/mkvmusic.tk/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:30 2014] [error] [client 199.30.20.15] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/mkvmusic.tk/2014
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:29 2014] [error] [client 198.143.38.65] client
>   denied by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:29 2014] [error] [client 198.143.38.65] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/download-strike-the-blood-all-episodes-720p-80mb-english-subbed-mediafire
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:20 2014] [error] [client 199.30.20.10] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/mkvmusic.tk/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:20 2014] [error] [client 199.30.20.10] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/mkvmusic.tk/2014
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:13 2014] [error] [client 5.255.253.38] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/androidnews/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:13 2014] [error] [client 5.255.253.38] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/androidnews/wp-content
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:09 2014] [error] [client 198.143.46.33] client
>   denied by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:09 2014] [error] [client 198.143.46.33] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/542102.jpg
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:07 2014] [error] [client 5.255.253.38] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/androidnews/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:07 2014] [error] [client 5.255.253.38] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/androidnews/wp-content
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:02 2014] [error] [client 65.55.215.34] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/hentai/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:17:02 2014] [error] [client 65.55.215.34] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/hentai/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/H62_Initiation_LRG.jpg
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:58 2014] [error] [client 198.143.39.1] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:58 2014] [error] [client 198.143.39.1] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:53 2014] [error] [client 180.76.6.146] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/backlinks/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:53 2014] [error] [client 180.76.6.146] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/backlinks/
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:47 2014] [error] [client 66.249.77.99] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/android/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:47 2014] [error] [client 66.249.77.99] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/android/2013
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:42 2014] [error] [client 66.249.77.71] client denied
>   by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/mkvmusic.tk/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:42 2014] [error] [client 66.249.77.71] client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/markgelo/public_html/mkvmusic.tk/2014
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:41 2014] [error] [client 199.21.148.44] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/android/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:41 2014] [error] [client 199.21.148.44] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/android/android-games
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:34 2014] [error] [client 157.55.33.182] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/markgiver/403.shtml
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:34 2014] [error] [client 157.55.33.182] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/markgiver/2013
>
> [Wed Apr 16 11:16:34 2014] [error] [client 157.55.33.182] client
>   denied by server configuration:
>   /home/markgelo/public_html/markgiver/403.shtml

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue today. It was a problem with `.htaccess` file of the server in my case.
You can find it in the `/public_html/` folder.

Rename it to `.htacces_old`, or with some other name, then try to reload a website page.

If you can't find this file - it may be because this is a hidden file. You can change it's visiblility on CPANEL > Settings, check a box "Show hidden files (dotfiles).

Answer (score 0):

One of your Wordpress security plugins checks each IP against a blacklist of IPs and if there is a match then that IP is not allowed to connect.

I checked 2 of the IPs listed above and one came up:

http://www.liveipmap.com/199.21.148.44 (open proxy)

and another came up

https://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_198.143.38.33 (spam harvester / comment spammer)

If you want to allow open proxy and comment spammers, you need to check every setting in your security plugin or find a different plugin to use).

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-better-wp-security-404-not-found-on-all-site-links

Go to the WP Dashboard --> Settings --> Permalinks

click on default and save changes.
Then click on Postname and save changes.

I have rechecked my logs throughout the last hour and there are NO errors in the logs! Woot!

Now if Bit51 would have addressed this directly ... it so would have solved a headache I really did not need today! UGH.

good luck!!